# How to stop the Role Assignment on the basis of certain condition in OIM 11g r2 PS3

Tags: event-handling, identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

I have coded one event handler to intercept the role_assignment and role_revoke operation.

I need to run some webservice on remote server and if response is 200 _ OK I want to do nothing.

But if response is not 200 I need to fail role assignment.

How should I do it?

Comment: When does your event run? Is this a PreProcess event?

Comment: Yes it is a preprocess event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should throw an `EventFailedException` from the body of your event handler's `execute` methods on a failure. This will flag the orchestration as having failed. A failed orchestration will call `compensate` on all event handlers that have already completed, and then exit cleanly in *FAILED* status. (You can query the `ORCHPROCESS` table to find the failed orchestration.)

See the JavaDoc for this exception here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oim/OMJAV/oracle/iam/platform/kernel/EventFailedException.html

And Oracle's documentation on developing custom event handlers here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27559_01/dev.1112/e27150/oper.htm#BGBHBIFH

(This is for an earlier version, but it's basically the same in later versions.)

Answer (score -1):

I would add something to the process task to handle the responses from the webservice there.

Comment: can you explain in more detail about your process task approach, as we are provisioning role where we can use process task?